# loading my script using getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

at first I'm loading all my js script in my header and it's all working properly. But I have one js file that need to be loaded inline/ load it in a certain page only.

this is the js file that I need to load

```
    var myScroll,pullDownEl, pullDownOffset, generatedCount = 0;
    function pullDownAction () {
            setTimeout(function () {    
                    var el, li, i;
                    el = document.getElementById('newlist');

                    if ( el.hasChildNodes() ) {
                            while ( el.childNodes.length >= 1 ) {
                                    el.removeChild( el.firstChild );       
                            } 
                    }

                    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
                            li = document.createElement('li');
                            li.innerText = 'Generated row ' + (++generatedCount);
                            el.insertBefore(li, el.childNodes[0]);
                    }

                    myScroll.refresh();     
            }, 1000);   
    }

    function loaded() {

            pullDownEl = document.getElementById('pullDown');
            pullDownOffset = pullDownEl.offsetHeight;

            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
                    //hideScrollbar: false,
                    //hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false, vScroll: false,
                    useTransition: true,
                    topOffset: pullDownOffset,
                    onRefresh: function () {
                            if (pullDownEl.className.match('loading')) {
                                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                                    $('#pullDown').css('display', 'inherit');
                                    $('#pullDown').css('display', 'none');
                                    $('#thelist').css('display', 'none');
                                    $('#newlist').css('display', 'inherit');
                            } 
                    },
                    onScrollMove: function () {
                            if (this.y > 5 && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                                    pullDownEl.className = 'flip';
                                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                                    $('#pullDown').css('display', 'inherit');
                                    this.minScrollY = 0;
                            } else if (this.y < 5 && pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                                    $('#pullDown').css('display', 'inherit');
                                    this.minScrollY = -pullDownOffset;
                            } 
                    },
                    onScrollEnd: function () {
                            if (pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                                    pullDownEl.className = 'loading';
                                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                                    pullDownAction();   
                            } 
                    }
            });

            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '0'; }, 800);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
```

loading it with my other script in my header it works but now I'm using the jquery getScript. It loads the script (using firebug) but when I tried calling the functions inside my js file it give me a two errors

1. Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
2. Cannot call method 'refresh' of undefined

This is how I call my js script using getScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.email').click(function (){
            $.getScript("assets/js/scroll.js",function() {
                    pullDownAction();
                    loaded();
            }); 
    });
});
```

Help anyone

Answer (score 0):

I know this may suggest more work than you want to do, but have you tried doing namespacing?  I do not know if this works 100% (as i am not sure of the reasoning why that is not working for you), but have you tried this?

```
(function( PullDown, $, undefined ) {
    //Private variables and this is a great way for minification, you will get the most out of it
    var myScroll,pullDownEl, pullDownOffset, generatedCount = 0;
    function pullDownAction () {
        //... your stuff here
    }

    function loaded() {
        //... more your stuff here
    }
}(window.PullDown = window.PullDown || {}, jQuery) // avoids name space collision w/ jQuery
```

Now do the same things, but with this edit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.email').click(function (){
            $.getScript("assets/js/scroll.js",function() {
                    window.PullDown.pullDownAction();
                    window.PullDown.loaded();
            }); 
    });
});
```

If i am not mistaken, or have bad copy and paste skills, this should work out just great!

Comment: Just becareful for namespace pollution, and i got this method of javascript writing from http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/